# Kusto KQL query to Extend multiple entities

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, azure-sentinel

I need to parse out the users names from multiple alerts within azure.

If i use the following extend i can get the data from '0'

`| extend Name = tostring(parse_json(Entities)[0].Name)`

but sometimes the data is at 6 or 9 ect, i can simple add a new line with "name2 = ...." but id need to know exactly how many entities there may be and this number might unmanageable.

Is there a way i can KQL to parse through all entities and create a new column for each .name entities

Answer (score 2):

you can use `mv-expand` or `mv-apply`